Where is this railroad track as seen in Rocky II during the training montage?
In Rocky II, during the second half of the training montage, there is this scene showing Rocky running down some rail road tracks.  I've been trying to match where on Google Maps this location could be, but haven't been able to find anything definitive.
It's likely in Philadelphia, as the movie takes place there and many (all?) other similar scenes from the montage were filmed in Philadelphia.

You can see this scene at 3:33 in this video as well.  Where is this location?

I don’t particularly have an issue with this question, per se, but I’m wondering why it’s not only still open, but has made it to HNQ. Shouldn’t it be closed as an ID question, which we’re told time and again are off-topic.

@Darren I asked on meta first and it appears to be on topic - I haven't received any other guidance otherwise. I do know "ID this show" is off topic, but this is "ID this location in this movie" which has a tag with over 100 questions... the tag guidance literally says "Use for questions trying to determine where a film was shot."

That’s fair. People trying to ID actors, songs etc are usually closed. I wasn’t in favour of that policy anyway TBH.

@Darren and TimothyG.: since recently, "ID this show" is on-topic again (a shocking return of the oft-controversial ID questions!), but this particular type of post ([tag:film-location]) has always been on-topic AFAIK.

Philly Magazine provides a nice breakdown of the various filming locations. The scene on the railroad is identified as

Lehigh Avenue train right-of-way
Yeah, so Rocky goes from deep South Philly to … running on the train tracks adjacent to Lehigh Avenue on the Richmond/Fishtown/Kensington border! Not so safe, and also incredibly far from South Philly. Here’s the route I imagined Rocky took: His house on Lambert to Passyunk, which he took all the way down to South Street. Then Fourth to Callowhill to Delaware Avenue (It wasn’t Columbus Boulevard then!) Delaware Avenue to Beach Street to Richmond to Schirra and back to Beach, which dead ends to a spot to sneak on to the train tracks. (Today, all the tracks have been removed except one.) Rocky runs on the tracks until the bridge on Kensington Ave that carries the El. He exits shortly down onto East Gurney Street, where at least today there is a seemingly good spot to leave. One great aspect of being Rocky is the train engineers merely say “Go Rocky!” instead of “Get the hell out of here before I call the cops!

The tracks have largely been removed, but the Kensington Ave Railroad
Bridge (1916) is still standing. Google Earth even highlights Rocky's house nearby :-)


Right as I finish my answer.  Great find! Rocky also runs across the bridge on B St. as can be seen in the same montage, when some kids are following him https://i.sstatic.net/O9WTgtK1.png This part I knew, but little did I know how close this scene was to that scene!

@TimothyG. - I enjoyed this question. Not only did it tax my searching skills, but I also learned something about the history of Philadelphia's railways and fine bridges :-) Sadly, I also learned that Kensington Avenue is not somewhere that anyone sane would go after dark.

Its an extremely depressing area now, to say the least.  A YouTuber by the name Peter Santenello recently released a pretty eye opening video of it two weeks ago (it has 4+ million views already).  Great watch if you are curious on how truly bad it is.

After hours of sifting around Google Maps, I believe this is around Kensington in Philadelphia, and Rocky is running what would be southeast towards Kensington Avenue.
Here is an image taken from the bridge on B Street around November 2018 (which is likely the bridge the camera is filming the shot from):

The bridge in the distance matches the the bridge seen in the distance of the screenshot from the movie.  It also has a tall (radio?) antenna beyond said bridge that you can also make out in the movie scene.  What threw me off is there appears to only be a single railroad track now in this line, instead of the many (11+) rail lines in the movie, but a lot can change since the 1970s.
Here's an overview image of the map:

Rocky would be running southeast towards Kensington Avenue (magenta arrow), which is where the bridge in the distance is.  If you a familiar with this area, you would know that the subway/SEPTA rail line runs parallel and above Kensington Avenue.  Rocky's house (as seen in the movie) is the green X, and the circled blue area is the factory-like building seen to the left of the bridge (which it seems to now be some sort of apartment buildings).
If you go to Google Street view, and go back in time to the 2014 imagery, you can see the old factory still, and the chimney that sticks out in the scene (though the chimney at this point in time was half collapsed it seems - circled in green).  This would be along Ruth street, looking northeast:


If you follow the Kensington tracks ENE for a while there's another nearly identical bridge that crosses over 5 tracks between E. Sedgley Ave. and E. Glenwood Ave./E. Venango Ave.  (Not sure when the name changes on that street.) Not quite the 11 tracks from the film, but more than the 1 at the other location.
